# How do I save an image as resource in Excel and reference it in Footer?

Tags: vba, excel, embedded-resource

I am trying to embed a logo in the footer of a dynamically generated spreadsheet.

My first thought was to see what "macro recorder" would provide.  Unfortunately, it references an image on the user's computer.  The problem is that, in most cases, this file will not exist, and I don't want the user to have to download an image for the VBA script to be functional.

Is it possible to store an image in a VBA-enabled spreadsheet as a resource and then reference it from the footer?

Comment: Could you distribute a zip file containing the spreadsheet and the logo?